# $2$ definitions of a reflective subcategory

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, morphism

Does it make any difference, in the definition of a reflective subcategory, if the reflection induced by $f$ goes directly to the codomain of $f$ **or** if we, on the contrary, insert  a reflection between codomain of $f$ and codomain of the reflection induced by $f$. In the former case it is understood that $f$ lies in the entire category while in the latter case that $f$ targets to the reflective part.

**EDIT**
Here $f$ is that "**arbitrary**" morphism from which domain leads the reflection (which will be the same if any other $g$ has the same domain) *and* which induces the unique morphism in the reflective subcategory which codomain leads (according to my problem) directly to the codomain of $f$ *or* [this is the question] to the codomain of another reflection. For your second query I cannot write which one of these 2 definitions I have in mind since I'm asking about their relationship. So my question is, which definition from the two is correct, in case that they are not equivalent.

**EDIT 2**

If this **EDIT 2** won't do the job I'll draw a picture and scan it in the next week. My question is, shall I postcompose any such $f$
with the reflection pertaining to $f$'s codomain, or is it equivalently enough that $f$ has the codomain in the reflective subcategory without post-composing it ?

**EDIT 3** Drawing has been done:
[image]

**EDIT 4** Obviously, $(2)\Longrightarrow(1)$.

Comment: What is $f$? Can you write out your question in more detail, with reference to a definition of reflective subcategory you have in mind?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is it better now ? I'm unable to draw here all the pictures. I have basically unraveled the classical definition via adjoints.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan A picture is worth a thousand words.